# System.InvalidOperationException was caught HResult=-2146233079 Message=Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 30

Tags: database, vb.net, oracle, oracle11g

I am having error in the executereader line. The Error shows an Internal .NET Framework Data Provider Error 30.

The Code I am trying to use is:

```
    Try
        Dim ss As String
        Dim oradb As String = "db credentials"
        Dim conn As New OracleConnection(oradb)
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "select m.branch_code from abc m where m.pfno='123'"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        dr.Read()
        ss = dr.Item("branch_code")
        conn.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception           
        Throw ex
    End Try
```

The detailed error report is shown below:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was caught  
HResult=-2146233079
 Message=Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 30.
 Source=System.Data.OracleClient
StackTrace:
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbBuffer.Validate(Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbBuffer.PtrToStringUni(Int32 offset)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OciHandle.PtrToString(NativeBuffer buf)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.get_ServerVersion()
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.get_ServerVersionAtLeastOracle8()
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.get_ServerVersionAtLeastOracle8()
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleColumn.Describe(Int32& offset, OracleConnection connection, OciErrorHandle errorHandle)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader.FillColumnInfo()
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader..ctor(OracleCommand command, OciStatementHandle statementHandle, String statementText, CommandBehavior commandBehavior)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
   at Mylogin.GetMapIDEfftdate() in D:\Projects\BranchManager 22-11-2018\BranchManager\Mylogin.aspx.vb:line 247
```

InnerException:

I am using Oracle Database Client 11g R2.

Comment: If you don't post the code where this error happens how we could be able to help you? This is not a guessing game.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question so that other users can understand and help you.

Comment: [edit] your question to add code, posting it in comments makes it unreadable

Comment: Somebody please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the unicode feature was already enabled in oracleDB but again I mentioned `unicode="TRUE"` in my connection string. So when I removed it, .Net worked properly.

So, you should check with your DB team whether any new update has been made to DB.

Comment: Thank You Arjun. I checked with my DB team and they said the same case you said. So I removed unicode = 'true' from my connection string and it is working perfectly fine now. Thank you again